# how pass-by-reference and pass-by-value works in python

Tags: python

I thought I understood python's pass-by-reference and pass-by-value processing...
can anyone explain what is the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value in python

Comment: A lot of mutable containers (i.e. lists, sets, class objects, etc) are pass-by-reference-like by default, meaning that they are shallowly copied in such that modifying the shallow copy modifies the original. Pass-by-value means that the values are copied over but the structure does not link to the original variable. You can achieve pass-by-value on a list or similar structure by deep copying, but sometimes you can leverage the shallow copy very efficiently. I don't feel like answering this question fully, so that's my 2 cents that can get you started while you wait for a full answer.

Comment: Python is always pass-by-value, never by reference. People just get confused about this due to the fact that **all** values in Python are references to objects. Nonetheless, those references are passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't really do either.  Python does "pass by assignment".  Python names are **always** references to object.  When you pass an object, the receiving function's parameter name gets another reference to the object.